# Nuget api request fails with internal server error

Tags: .net, api, nuget

I am trying to upload a new version of my package to Nuget.

I am using the below command:

`dotnet nuget push <pathToFile> -k <APIkey> -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

The output I get is:

```
info : Pushing <packageName> to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
info :   InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 968ms
info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
info :   InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 336ms
info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
info :   InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 268ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

I checked [status.nuget.org](https://status.nuget.org) and it's systems all green.

I have been trying for days and it's always the same.

EDIT:

As per advice in the comments I tried publishing the package using the following command:

`nuget push <packageName> -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` (I set my API key before that)

Same problem:

```
Pushing <packageName> to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 11190ms
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1400ms
  PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
  InternalServerError https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 1384ms
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe use nuget.exe just to verify if that doesn't work either. After that maybe install Fiddler and check details of these requests.

Comment: @Peska, thank you, can you advise me what to look for in the requests?

Comment: Just check response body - maybe there will be more explanation than just 500 Internal Server Error.